# WPF - Making ListView (GridView) Scroll when too much data?

Tags: wpf, listview, scroll

```
<Grid>
  <ListView ItemsSource="....">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn ......../>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

When there are thousands of rows the above XAML causes the `Grid` to size larger than the form and the data becomes hidden.

What I want to do is to keep the `ListView` so that it fills the grid (which fills the form), and to have a vertical scrollbar to scroll through the items (leaving the header row in place at the top).  Just like a WinForm grid would.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?  I don't want to use 3rd party components.

Thanks

Comment: That should actually work.  I'm guessing its something outside of the code that you posted.  what's your grid inside of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your `Grid` is hosted in a `StackPanel`. Get rid of that and it should work fine.

Comment: Yep, I had a stack panel to put a label above the ListView.  I switched to using Margin instead and now the scrollbar appears.

Thanks!

Comment: In my case the problematic Llistview was in page loaded inside a Frame. The Frame itself was inside a StackPanel and that was the culprit. So I would check the hierarchy all the way from the ListView to the root frame