# WPF How to Scroll ListView embedded in Grid

Tags: wpf, listview, grid, scroll

I am trying to scroll a listview control in WPF which is embedded in a Grid layout control. I can't seem to achieve this. Any ideas anyone?

By the way i have set the following properties on the list view in the xaml markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Top Area-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Price, Volume and Ratio Stats">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Row 1-->
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbSellInstrumentCode" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Sell Share</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtSellInstrumentCode" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbBuyInstrumentCode" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">Buy Share</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBuyInstrumentCode" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTargetPriceRatio" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">Target Trigger</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTargetPriceRatio" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTradedPriceRatio" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0">Traded Price Ratio</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTradedPriceRatio" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <!--Row 2-->
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbBidPrice" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Bid Price</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBidPrice" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbAskPrice" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">Ask Price</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAskPrice" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbMarketPriceRatio" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">Market Trigger</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtMarketPriceRatio" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTradedVolumeRatio" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1">Traded Volume Ratio</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTradedVolumeRatio" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <!--Row 3-->
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbBidVolume" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Bid Volume</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBidVolume" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbAskVolume" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">Ask Volume</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAskVolume" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTradedSpread" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2">Traded Spread</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTradedSpread" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTradedAmountRatio" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2">Traded Amount Ratio</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTradedAmountRatio" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <!--Middle Area-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Average Price, Total Volumes and Averages Stats">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Row 1-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Total Sell Volume</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTotalSellVolume" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">Total Buy Volume</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTotalBuyVolume" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <!--Row 2-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Total Sell Amount (ZAR)</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTotalSellAmount" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">Total Buy Amount (ZAR)</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTotalBuyAmount" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <!--Row 3-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Average Sell Price (ZAR)</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAverageSellPrice" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">Average Buy Price (ZAR)</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAverageBuyPrice" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <!--Row 4-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">Number of Unfilled Orders</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtNumberOfUnfilledOrders" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3">Slippage (ZAR)</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtSlippage" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="lvSellTrades" Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=hh:mm:ss tt}" Header="Date"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AccountCode}" Header="Account Code"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" Header="Sell Price"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Volume, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" Header="Sell Volume"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=R {0:N2}}" Header="Amount"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="lvBuyTrades" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=hh:mm:ss tt}" Header="Date"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AccountCode}" Header="Account Code"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" Header="Buy Price"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Volume, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" Header="Buy Volume"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=R {0:N2}}" Header="Amount"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you put it inside the ScrollViewer? <ScrollViewer>
  Content
</ScrollViewer>

Comment: Hi Lukas, tried your suggestion - no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i've gathered from [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379189/wpf-making-listview-gridview-scroll-when-too-much-data), If your grid is hosted inside a stackpanel, it could cause issues.

Comment: I was using a DockPanel to host the Grid. Got rid of that and replaced it with another Grid. Still the same effect.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the XAML, could you also describe the nature of your issue a little clearer. I'm unsure exactly what functionality you're hoping to achieve or what functionality currently have

Comment: All i am trying to do is to get automatic vertical scroll functionality for lvSellTrades and lvBuyTrades. Currently, when the listviews exceed the visible areas, they do not display vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Hi Val, your answer is correct. The XAML from above was in a user control which was hosted in another window, and that windows layout control was a stackpanel. Changed it and everything works great! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `VerticalAlignment` property on `ListView` to `Top`. If this does not help try to wrap `ListView` with `ScrollViewer` (`ListView.VerticalAlignment` should have `Top` value).

Comment: Tried that - no difference. See edited code of original post.

Comment: For me it works without ScrollViewer with no problem in VS2010.